# Android Studio Crashing Error- How to Solve this Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I'm writing an Android application that contains TextInputLayout control for login page. The issue is every time I run the application I got a crashing error which leads to close up the application. I traced the error and found that this line of code causes the error.

```
    **TextUserName= [enter image description here][1]findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);**
```

The image of this error is attached.

Please guide me on solve on how to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your question properly other developer will answer your question

Comment: I think I posted very clear! if you need further clarification I'm ready